# Recording voice is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, uiactivityviewcontroller

In my app, I want to record voice and send via email. I am recording voice and once I click the attach button, it throws me the following error. It seems voice is not recorded.

[image]

Here is my code snippet

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                               @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                               nil];
    NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

    NSLog(@"%@",outputFileURL);

    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

    // Define the recorder setting
    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    // Initiate and prepare the recorder
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:NULL];
    recorder.delegate = self;
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
}

- (IBAction)microButton:(id)sender {

    if(counter%2==0)
    {
        if (!recorder.recording) {
            AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
            [session setActive:YES error:nil];
            // Start recording
            [recorder record];
        }
        counter=counter+1;
    }
    else{
        [recorder stop];

        AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];
            counter=counter+1;
    }
}

- (void) audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)avrecorder successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    NSLog(@"audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying");
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Done" message: @"Voice recorded successfully!"delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}


- (IBAction)attachBtn:(id)sender {    

 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *URL = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyAudioMemo.m4a"];

NSString* someText = @"Voice";
NSURL *urlToShare = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:URL isDirectory:NO];
NSArray* dataToShare = @[someText, urlToShare];

UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare
                                  applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint,UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact];
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;

activityViewController.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
    //if (completed) {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    //}
};

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is on an iPad, when you present the `UIActivityViewController`, it will be shown in a popover. You need to do what the message states, set either the `sourceView` or the `barButtonItem`.

```
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = sender;
```

That assumes `sender` is a `UIBarButtonItem`. If it's a `UIButton` or other view, use:

```
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = sender;
```

Comment: could you please elaborate a little in detail?

Comment: What more do you need? Add the line of code I showed just after you create your `UIActivityViewController`.

Comment: I have created a popover and once I click on attach button, my popover appears, what would be the next step to follow?

Comment: What popover? The code you posted in your question doesn't show you creating your own popover anywhere. Isn't the issue with the `UIActivityViewController`? If so, just add the one line I put in my answer.

Comment: I have added, see my updated code, still it is not working, and now it is also giving me the [UIButton view]: unrecognized selector error

Comment: OK, I assumed `sender` was a `UIBarButtonItem`. Since it is a `UIButton`, change `barButtonItem` to `sourceView`.